# Group of objects

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qtwidgets

In my Qt5 program I'm working on multiple objects and it's taking a lot of time and code to disable or change state of 20 checkboxes. Is there any option to make a group of checkboxes (or any other objects) and perform commands on it with one line?

For instance:

```
QCheckBox b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
QCheckBox_Group Box_1to5 = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5};
ui->Box_1to5->setEnabled(false);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve exactly. There's QButtonGroup: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html, but that's more for exclusive groups where only one button can be checked at a time. If it's about enabling/disabling: if all checkboxes are inside the same parent, you could just enable/disable the parent. Or put the checkboxes into vectors and iterate over them.

Comment: @Frank, that should be an answer, not a comment, because you've about covered it. I'd just add that another way is to create a custom group class by wrapping those vectors (or, rather, `QList`s).

Comment: Make your own checkbox manager and implement any operationon the over the group of object. If you don't want separate class then just do it in simple loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frank's comment is what you want for simply enabling/disabling a set of widgets, but I'll answer your more general question of how to apply a change of state to a set of objects. If you are free to use C++11, then the following will give you the general ability to call any member function on any object with a common set of function arguments:

```
// Member functions without arguments
template<typename ObjectPtrs, typename Func>
void  batchApply(ObjectPtrs objects, Func func)
{
    for (auto object : objects)
    {
        (object->*func)();
    }
}

// Member functions with 1 or more arguments
template<typename ObjectPtrs, typename Func, typename ... Args>
void  batchApply(ObjectPtrs objects, Func func, Args ... args)
{
    for (auto object : objects)
    {
        (object->*func)(args ...);
    }
}
```

With the above, you can achieve your goal of being able to call a function on a set of objects with a single line of code. You would use it something like this:

```
QCheckbox  b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
auto Box_1to5 = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5};

batchApply(Box_1to5, &QCheckbox::setChecked, false);
batchApply(Box_1to5, &QCheckbox::toggle);
```

The one limitation of the above method is that it doesn't handle default function arguments, so even if a function has a default argument, you have to explicitly provide one. For example, the following will result in a compiler error because `animateClick` has one argument (its default value is ignored):

```
batchApply(Box_1to5, &QCheckbox::animateClick);
```

The above technique uses *variadic templates* to support any number and type of function arguments. If you are not yet familiar with these, you may find the following useful:

https://crascit.com/2015/03/21/practical-uses-for-variadic-templates/

Answer (score 2):

You can define a single signal and connect that to all of the checkboxes:

```
/* In the constructor or at the start*/
QVector<QCheckbox*> boxes{b1, b2, b3, b4, b5};
for(QCheckbox* box: boxes) {
    connect(this, &MyWidget::setBoxCheckedState, box, &QCheckbox::setChecked); 
}

/* Somewhere in the code where the state should change */
emit setBoxCheckedState(true); // <- custom signal on your class
```

or you can use the for_each algorithm:

```
bool checked = true; 
std::for_each(boxes.begin(), boxes.end(), [checked](QCheckbox* box) { 
    box->setChecked(checked);
});
```